# Run command in interactive ncat shell via bash script

Tags: bash, netcat

I have the below bash script and I'm trying to get the subsequent python command to run within the Ncat shell once a connection is established. Is there a way to do this?

`#!/bin/bash
ncat -vnl 443 --ssl
python -c 'import pty;pty.spawn("/bin/bash")'`

Comment: Wouldn't you be better served using ssh?

Comment: I could use ssh but this is to receive connections from a penetration test box that's been placed on client premises. We need to ssh in to the receiving server (that this script is run on) so I want to keep the ssh port as 22. An encrypted connection via Ncat to port 443 should bypass client firewall rules while keeping the ssh port as 22 on my server.

Comment: If it definitely has to be nc then you could redirect the nc output to a pipe file and then have another process monitor this file, spawning the Python process when the file is created.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've come up with is to have Ncat run a bash script containing the python command on the penetration test box when a connection is established rather than /bin/bash. This way only the listener is required on the server and we get our fully interactive shell.